# Django admin page error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates

I was creating a Django app. Doing so i enabled the Django admin site and i could see it working fine. Then i created some models and inserted data into it through the form in my app. But i am not able to see the entered values through admin panel of Django. I found that its because i havent included an admin.py file in my application folder. Then i created an admin.py file, ran syndb and tried. Now its throwing an error

`ImportError at /admin/

No module named UniversityDetails.models`

I will paste my admin.py, models.py and project folder structure. Please help me to solve this.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class UniversityDetails(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.TextField()
    birthday = models.TextField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**admin.py**

```
from universityDetails.models import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(UniversityDetails)
```

Project Name :**universityDB**
Application Name : **universityDetails**

**TRACEBACK**

```
    Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://10.1.0.90:8080/admin/
Django Version: 1.2.5
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'universityDetails',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      91.                         request.path_info)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
      215.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
      244.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
      239.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
      35.     __import__(name)
    File "/home/rv/Desktop/universityDB/../universityDB/urls.py" in <module>
      5. admin.autodiscover()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in autodiscover
      24.             import_module('%s.admin' % app)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
      35.     __import__(name)
    File "/home/rv/Desktop/universityDB/universityDetails/admin.py" in <module>
      1. from UniversityDetails.models import *

    Exception Type: ImportError at /admin/
    Exception Value: No module named UniversityDetails.models
```

Comment: I thought you said you changed line 1 to my version? What is the traceback when you change the import line to `from universityDB.universityDetails.models import *`?

Comment: This is the traceback with the modification u told me.

Comment: This traceback says line 1 of `universityDetails/admin.py` is `from UniversityDetails.models import *` - Are you restarting the server?

Comment: yes...i am restarting the server..!

Comment: That's so odd.. A line that doesn't exist appearing in the traceback. I've only seen something like this with old `.pyc` files lying around and causing mayhem. Try deleting your .pyc files. Otherwise, it's out of my league. Good luck rv_k! I gotta get to sleep.

Comment: tried that too..but still throwing same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
from universityDB.universityDetails.models import *
from django.contrib import admin

class UniversityDetailsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['firstName ', 'lastName ']
    list_display = ('firstName ', 'lastName ')    
    search_fields = ['firstName ', 'lastName ']

admin.site.register(UniversityDetails,UniversityDetailsAdmin)
```

Comment: try `from universityDB.universityDetails.models.UniversityDetails`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like UniversityDetails isn't in your python path, have you added it yet?

Comment: how can we add it to python path?

Answer (score 1):

The typical django setup puts the project's parent directory on the Python Path, meaning your models are resolved via `MyProject.MyApp.models`

If you can import `universityDB` (you would need to or you'd have more / different problems), you should change line 1 of your `admin.py` to `from universityDB.universityDetails.models import *` and you should be set.

Comment: that didnt fix my problem..i made the change u told..still it throws the same error. I has a logn and registration page, its throwing the same error for all the pages i select now..

Comment: Which line in what file is triggering this error? The error says no module named `UniversityDetails.models` -- did you mistype `universityDetails` as `UniversityDetails` somewhere else?

Comment: The exception Location is "Exception Location:  /home/rv/Desktop/universityDB/universityDetails/admin.py in <module>, line 1"

Comment: my model class names is UniversityDetails . and app name is universityDetails.

Comment: I'm wondering why your error message says `UniversityDetails` when you haven't specified that anywhere. The exact same exception occurs when you change the line to what I wrote above?

Comment: Ok, will you copy and paste your traceback?

Comment: Well I gotta go, but definitely look into why your code is throwing an exception for code you don't have -- line 1 should have been modified. Make sure you're restarting the server!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following :

from models import *

and put your admin.py file in your model folder

Answer (score 0):

try turning managed = false in the model name (delete the managed = false in meta of model class)