# django admin.py for an app

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm following the tutorial contained here:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html

The instructions are to create a file called admin.py in the app folder with this code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.books.models import Publisher, Author, Book

admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book)
```

However, after I do this I get an error at the second line that says:

No module named books.models

I found a similar question here but didn't understand the answer:

[Django admin page error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467927/django-admin-page-error)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you have a module named `books` and an `__init__.py` file in it?

Comment: Where is your `books` app relative to the `mysite` directory? Is your Django project in fact named "mysite"?

Comment: It is not named mysite, but that wasn't the mistake I was making - in my file i had it with the correct project name djangobook1. Please see my explanation below of what fixed it, perhaps you can help me clarify the behavior. Basically I had to change it to just from books.models import Publisher, Author, Book

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a `__init__.py` in the books directory so Python recognizes it as a module.

Comment: I do have `__init__.py` in my books directory, which is in my project directory. This was created automatically by python manage.py startapp books

Comment: you need it in the folder `books/` too

Comment: Run `python manage.py shell` and try `import mysite.books` from there and see what it says

Comment: It is in C:\Users\username\djangobook1\books, where djangobook1 is the project directory. Am I supposed to have a second books folder...

Comment: Have you added books to your installed apps in settings.py?

Comment: Ethan, it gives me the same error. I have added it to installed apps, simply as 'books', not a full path or anything...

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually created your `Book` model yet? The following is the model definition from [the tutorial you're following](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html):

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Yes, I have that as well as the Publisher and Author models in models.py in the books directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer here:

[ImportError: No module named books.models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296126/importerror-no-module-named-books-models)

For whatever reason, because in the settings file I just have 'books' under installed apps, my admin.py should read:

from books.models import Publisher, Author, Book

instead of

from djangobook1.books.models import Publisher, Author, Book

Now I'm not sure what the rule here is, but this fixed my issue...

Comment: Actually, it's acceptable to use `books.models` _or_ `mysite.books.models`. Django doesn't fuss if you connote that an app resides within your project directory (assuming that it actually does).